# Can we limit a queue by number of messages?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a use case where a queue must contain only 1 message, and it must get replaced with any new message.

So, if there is no listener to the queue the above explanation comes in action. If the listener is listening to queue then it consumes the message. So the queue has a max limit as 1.

I have searched a lot for this feature in ActiveMQ "Classic." Any guidance would definitely help.

**Note**: There is a ["ring" queue in ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ring-queues.html) that would accomplish this, but we are looking for this feature in ActiveMQ "Classic." [A Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5522) is raised for this.

Comment: ActiveMQ Artemis supports OpenWire so you should be able to migrate any existing clients without any code or library changes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no comparable feature in ActiveMQ to limit Queue depth to a fixed number of messages.  If you really need such a thing then you should perhaps pursue a migration to ActiveMQ Artemis as that has this feature built in.